# Change time signature in MusicSequence

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, midi, musicsequence

I'm trying to change the time signature (default to 4/4) in a [MusicSequence](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html) but I don't seem to understand how to do this. I have 2 [MusicTracks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html) inside the sequence and a MusicPlayer also to reproduce the music. How can I change this value?

**EDIT:**

I know now that I need to add a Time Sig event to the MusicSequence Tempo Track. I know that I can get this track with [MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack), but how do I add a time sig event to it?

**EDIT 2:**

Researching I realized that i need to create an [MusicTrackExtendedMetaEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/MusicTrackNewMetaEvent) to the Music Tempo Track. Now I need to know how to correctly format [MIDIMetaEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MIDIMetaEvent) (I know that 88 is the metaEventType but don't know how to add the rest of the information).

Comment: Did you end up figuring out how to create time signiture mete event?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 4 wasting 4 hours on this I figured out how to do it. Here the code:

```
//Getting the tempo track
MusicTrack tempoTrack;
MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack (musicSequence, &tempoTrack);

//Set time signature to 7/16
MIDIMetaEvent timeSignatureMetaEvent;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.metaEventType = 0x58;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.dataLength = 4;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.data[0] = 0x07;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.data[1] = 0x04;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.data[2] = 0x18;
timeSignatureMetaEvent.data[3] = 0x08;
MusicTrackNewMetaEvent(tempoTrack, 0, &timeSignatureMetaEvent);
```

Here's a reference to MIDI file spec to look up time signature codes to http://www.somascape.org/midi/tech/mfile.html

Comment: Remember to first clear the Tempo Track or you'll end up with 2 Time Signatures in your MIDI file. 

`code`MusicTrack tempoTrack;

    MusicSequenceGetTempoTrack(sequence, &tempoTrack);

    MusicTrackClear(tempoTrack, 0, 1); `code`

Comment: MIDIMetaEvent only allocates 1 byte for data, who knows what memory you are writing the other 3 bytes to.

Comment: Time signature is expressed as 4 numbers. nn and dd represent the "numerator" and "denominator" of the signature as notated on sheet music. The denominator is a negative power of 2: 2 = quarter note, 3 = eighth, 4 = 16 etc. http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midifile/time.htm